# clearing without a wrapping 'row' container

Tags: css, clearfix

Is there a way to clear after the last element of a row without a wrapping container per row?
The column sizes inside will vary, there is a 'last' class, can I clear after that div is closed? I can't add anything to the markup.

Markup:

```
<div class="grid-row">
   <div class="col-6">
     col 6   
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 last">
     col 6   
  </div> 
 <!-- Need to clear here -->
  <div class="col-4">
      col 4   
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
      col 4  
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 last">
      col 4  
  </div>
  <!-- Need to clear here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how you want to clear this? Javascript? jQuery?

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS solution but I don't think it's possible. So Jquery would be be the next option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `.last` column that has following siblings (is not the last child), you can simply introduce clearance with the next sibling:

```
.grid-row .last + div {
    clear: both;
}
```

As for the very last child, you can either use a clearfix `:after` pseudo-element on `.grid-row`:

```
.grid-row:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Or you can have the element following `.grid-row` introduce clearance, in much the same way as the first CSS rule above.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend `:after` on `.grid-row`?

Comment: @bfrohs: Actually on second thought, it makes sense here, since it would basically serve the same purpose as other elements in the first CSS rule.

Comment: Looks to do the trick! Will have a further play then mark it as answer! Thank you.